# AWS instance scheduler is not able to shut down RDS instances based on DynamoDb tag, are there any additional requirements needed?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created an AWS RDS and attached a tag created from the dynamoDb to schedule the RDS to be shutdown at EOD at 7:00pm, however, the tag isn't properly shutting off the RDS instance. Checking the log data in cloudwatch, I don't notice any log data showing that the tag is properly identifying any RDS instances and the name matches the tag in the dynamodb. Are there any additional requirements needed for AWS RDS to shutdown at EOD with the instance scheduler?

Comment: what is your shutdown code?

Comment: {
  "begintime": {
    "S": "07:00"
  },
  "description": {
    "S": "Set to 7:00am start; 7:00pm end; Mon-Fri"
  },
  "endtime": {
    "S": "23:00"
  },
  "name": {
    "S": "instance-scheduler-period-rds"
  },
  "type": {
    "S": "period"
  },
  "weekdays": {
    "SS": [
      "mon-fri"
    ]
  }
}

Comment: I created this via the dynamodb as a test. The begin time has been set to an arbitrary value, it was the endtime I was testing primarily. Checking the log data, the rds instances that are tagged are not being registered every 5 min at all.Could this be due to any IAM permissions that need to be set?

Comment: this is a record of dynamodb table not the scheduling code. Where is the code?

Comment: Are you referring to the template used to create the stack in the dynamodb? This is the link I used for that: 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/solutions-reference/aws-instance-scheduler/latest/instance-scheduler.template